# Redirecting for mobile web browsers

Tags: browser, redirect, mobile

Is there a way to redirect for mobile web pages; and what is the best layout for mobile browsers? I currently have my pages set to relative sizing via percentages.

Comment: I've been wondering about the redirecting myself, actually - I know there's a way to do it.  I'm assuming it's based on checking the browser version and comparing it to a list of mobile browsers, then redirecting if appropriate; however, I haven't seriously looked into it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/). It will give you information on mobile device's capabilities that you will be able to use to render your mobile pages accordingly.

It has binging for a lot of server side languages, including, but not limited to, PHP, ASP.NET and Java.

You will configure your web application to include information about the device for each request. You will use that information to render mobile web pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Categorizr](http://goo.gl/FV4cR). It's been tested against data in WURFL and can detect mobile devices, tablets, smartTVS, and desktops.